# My html form won't POST to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Hello i have a problem where my data isn't being put into my MYSQL database.
Also there isn't any errors at all on screen or in the php error page.
My code is below.

This is my array with all the data in

```
  $time_submit = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());
            $submit_data = array(
                'time_submit'               => $time_submit,
                'time_event'                => $_POST['date'] . " " . $_POST['hr'] . ":" . $_POST['min'],
                'project_number'            => $_POST['project'],
                'event'                     => $_POST['event'],
                'happened'                  => $_POST['happened'],
                'about_it'                  => $_POST['about_it'],
                'reporter_name'             => $_POST['reporter'],
                'organisation'              => $_POST['organisation'],
                'trackside'                 => $_POST['trackside'],
                'event_location'            => $_POST['location'],
                'phone_number'              => $_POST['number'],
                'yes_rules'                 => $_POST['rules'],
                'life_rules'                => $_POST['life_rules'],
                'require_feedback'          => $_POST['feedback'],
                'reporter_email'            => $_POST['email'],
                'region'                    => $_POST['region'],
                'photo'                     => $file_path
                    );
                    submit_form($submit_data);
```

I have a function that submits the data

```
function submit_form($submit_data) {
    global $conn;
    array_walk($submit_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($submit_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $submit_data) . '\'';

    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tb_data($fields) VALUES($data)");

}
```

I have echoed everything to make sure its all okay and everything looks fine.

My form

```
<form id="closecall" action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul class="form">
            <li><label><i>* Fields marked with an asterix are required</i></label></li><br />
            <? echo output_errors($errors); ?>
            <li><label for="date"><i>* </i>Event Date and time:<i class="required" id="datepicker_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li>
                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="date" >
                &nbsp;
                <select name="hr" id="hr">
                    <option value="">Hr</option>
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="00">00</option>
                </select>
                <select name="min" id="min">
                    <option value="">Min</option>
                    <option value="00">00</option>
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    <option value="32">32</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="34">34</option>
                    <option value="35">35</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="37">37</option>
                    <option value="38">38</option>
                    <option value="39">39</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="41">41</option>
                    <option value="42">42</option>
                    <option value="43">43</option>
                    <option value="44">44</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="46">46</option>
                    <option value="47">47</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="49">49</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="51">51</option>
                    <option value="52">52</option>
                    <option value="53">53</option>
                    <option value="54">54</option>
                    <option value="55">55</option>
                    <option value="56">56</option>
                    <option value="57">57</option>
                    <option value="58">58</option>
                    <option value="59">59</option>
                </select>
            </li><br />
            <li><label for="Project"><i>* </i>Involved Project:<i class="required" id="project_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li><input id="project" name="project" type="text"></li><br />
            <li><label for="Event"><i>* </i>Describe the Event:<i class="required" id="event_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li><textarea class="textarea" id="event" name="event"></textarea></li><br />
            <li><label for="happened"><i>* </i>What Could Have Happened:<i class="required" id="happened_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li><textarea class="textarea" id="happened" name="happened"></textarea></li><br />
            <li><label for="about_it"><i>* </i>What were you able to do about it:<i class="required" id="about_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li><textarea class="textarea" id="about_it" name="about_it"></textarea></li><br />
            <li><label for="reported">Reported By:</label></li>
            <li><input id="reported" name="reporter" type="text"/></li><br />
            <li><label for="organisation"><i>* </i>Organisation:<i class="required" id="organisation_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li><input id="organisation" name="organisation" type="text"></li><br />
            <li><label for="trackside"><i>* </i>Trackside or Non-Trackside:</label></li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="trackside" value="Trackside"><span>Trackside</span>
                <input type="radio" name="trackside" value="Non-Trackside" checked><span>Non-Trackside including Civils and Aiports</span>
            </li><br />
            <li><label for="location">Other Location Info (Stand No./ELR/Mileage etc):</label></li>
            <li class="optional"><span>(If Known)</span></li>
            <li><input id="location" name="location" type="text"/></li><br />
            <li><label for="number">Reporters Mobile Number:</label></li>
            <li><input id="contact" name="number" type="text"/></li><br />
            <li><label for="rules"><i>* </i>Potential Breach of Life Saving Rules? (Not Applicable to Airports):</label></li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="rules" class="rules" value="Yes" ><span>Yes</span>
                <input type="radio" name="rules" class="rules" value="No"checked><span>No</span>
            </li><br />

            <li class="liferules" style="display: none;"><label for="liferules"><i>* </i>Life Saving Rules (Not Applicable to Airports):<i class="required" id="rules_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li class="liferules" style="display: none;">
                <select  name="life_rules" id="liferules">
                    <option value="">Please Select!</option>
                    <option value="Working with electricity">Working with electricity</option>
                    <option value="Working with electricity-test before touch">Working with electricity-test before touch</option>
                    <option value="Always obey the speed limit and wear a seat belt.">Always obey the speed limit and wear a seat belt.</option>
                    <option value="Never use a hand-held or hands-free phone, or programme any other mobile device, while driving.">Never use a hand-held or hands-free phone, or programme any other mobile device, while driving.</option>
                    <option value="Working at height-without a harness">Working at height-without a harness</option>
                    <option value="Equipment fit for intended purpose">Equipment fit for intended purpose</option>
                    <option value="Under the influence of Drugs or Alcohol">Under the influence of Drugs or Alcohol</option>
                    <option value="Wasn't trained for the job at hand">Wasn't trained for the job at hand</option>
                    <option value="Entered exclusion zone(Without permission)">Entered exclusion zone(Without permission)</option>
                    <option value="Plans and Permits Weren't in place before Job">Plans and Permits Weren't in place before Job</option>
                </select>
            </li><br />

            <li><label for="feedback"><i>* </i>Does the Reporter Require Close Call Feedback:</label></li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio"  name="feedback" class="feedback" value="Yes" ><span>Yes</span>
                <input type="radio"  name="feedback" class="feedback" value="No"  checked/><span>No</span>
            </li><br />
            <li class="email" style="display: none;"><label for="email"><i>* </i>Please enter your email address:<i class="required" id="feedback_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li class="email" style="display: none;"><input id="feedback" type="email" name="email"></li><br />
            <li><label for="region"><i>* </i>Region:<i class="required" id="region_info">Required</i></label></li>
            <li>
                <select id="region" name="region">
                    <option value="">Please Select!</option>
                    <option value="Wales and Western">Wales and Western</option>
                    <option value="Central">Central</option>
                    <option value="Southern">Southern</option>
                    <option value="Airports">Airports</option>
                </select>
            </li><br />
            <li><label><i>* Max 5MB Photos and PDF's only </i>Do you want to upload a file:</label></li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio"  name="upload" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span>
                <input type="radio"  name="upload" value="No"  checked/><span>No</span>
            </li><br />
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileload"><label for="image">File Upload:</label></li><br />
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileload"><input id="file0" type="file" name="file1" ></li><br />
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileload"><input name="button" type="button" value="Upload More"></li><br />
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileshow"><input type="file" name="file2"></li>
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileshow"><input type="file" name="file3"></li>
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileshow"><input type="file" name="file4"></li>
            <li style="display: none;" class="fileshow"><input type="file" name="file5"></li><br />
            <li><i class="required" id="end_info">Please fill out required fields!</i></li>
            <li><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" ></li>
            <li></li>
```

I know the way i do my time is wrong and i am going to change it.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: there is no errors on screen or in the php error page

Comment: Don't try to sanitize your own data. Take advantage of mysqli's parameter binding.

Comment: does it hurt sanitising it again?

Comment: Just forget mysql_* ext which is deprecated, use mysqli as said before or PDO (then you can just send the data to it and it will do all the work for you !)

Comment: but i haven't used mysql i always use mysqli i just have an array walk sanitize.

Comment: Don't sanitize it in the first place. You can check for valid options, but you'll just run into problems sanitizing it. When you bind your parameters, the database will take care of it all for you.

Comment: i do have short tags enabled and use them everywhere is that a bad thing

Comment: i have removed the array walk and it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you bind your parameters?

Comment: i have used this in another of my forms and works perfectly but it won't work on this one and i don't have a clue why

Comment: i don't know how you mean bind parameters

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php and http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: But im not using PDO

Comment: Neither of those links are using PDO either..

Comment: the thing is this exact same code works on my other form but not this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for MySQL Error with mysqli_error

```
if (!mysql_query($conn, ...)) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```